# How to call java script in android?

Tags: android

I am new to java script using in android,I have function in js file to convert user name,how to send i/p values to this and  how to retrieve data for this file in android activity button click.if any one have idea please tell me thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used webview?

Answer (score 1):

tru out this :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);



web.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());

web.addJavascriptInterface(new DemoJavaScriptInterface(), "temp_1");

web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/temp_1.html");

}   
}

final class DemoJavaScriptInterface {

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
WebView web;
DemoJavaScriptInterface() {
}

public void clickOnAndroid() {
mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        web.loadUrl("javascript:init();");
      }
});
```

}
   }

```
final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "WebViewDemo";
@Override

public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, message);
    result.confirm();
    return true;
}
}
```